# Is there any reliable way to find a company address by domain using Google geocoding or some other API?

Tags: geocoding, google-geocoding-api

Most of companies can be geocoded by domain name using Google geocoding API.
For example I can give 'microsoft.com' and the API will return the same address with 'Microsoft'.

However if I try it for some other companies they can be found by name, but cannot be found by domain. For example if I enter 'RAD campaign', I get proper results. But if I use 'radcampaign.com' I get zero results. Google definitely 'knows' about website of this company, because if I search this company on Google maps, I see their website URL in the info panel.

So is there any reliable way to find a company address by domain. I mean exactly not server location, not domain registrant location but an address that is mentioned on the website.